# How do I use qemu-bridge-helper to get a virtual server running on my local network?

Tags: networking, qemu

I would like to access my virtual server from anywhere on my local network. I'd prefer to use `qemu-bridge-helper` so as to simplify the networking, since i'm weak in that area. After reading [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#Bridged_networking_using_qemu-bridge-helper), attempting to comprehend [the Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/QEMU#Host_configuration), and watching [an unsuccessful tutorial on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Q1PebvpQUvI), i figured i've boiled down my needs to a few simple commands--but i still don't know where i'm going wrong. Below is my configuration:

#### Host Configuration (arch linux)

```
# Create the bridge
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip link set dev br0 up

# Not sure if this is necessary. Causes loss of connectivity on host.
ip link set eth0 master br0

# Assign an IP address to the bridge
dhcpd br0

# Firewall passthrough?
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# /etc/qemu/bridge.conf
allow br0
```

#### qemu script

```
# `qemu-bridge-helper` creates & configures a `tap0` interface, and also sets it as the bridge's master
qemu-start-script -net nic,model=virtio -net bridge,br=br0
```

#### Guest/Server Configuration (arch linux)

```
systemctl start dhcpcd
```

Basic network connectivity from VM-to-router is all i'm after. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was a conflict with using both `netctl` and `NetworkManager` to connect the Host to the internet. Switching exclusively to `NetworkManager` resolved the issue.

Comment: And how exactly dido you switch to `NetworkManager`? Which commands did you use?